# How to retrieve lost username/ email log- in ?

Tags: username

I have couple of blogs hosted by wordpress.com (e.g. myspecialcorner.wordpress.com), and i have not been able to remember the username email log- n used for this wordpress.

For your advise on how can I solve the above problem.

Thanks.

Comment: forgot even email? why don't you [try here](https://wordpress.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword) with all the emails you remember?

Answer (score 0):

Without the email it will be hard, Wordpress likely will not be willing to release that info. You will have a few options:

1. Try any email you would have used in the forgot password function.
2. Search all your emails for the emails you got initially.
3. Wordpress sends update emails periodically so whichever one has gotten those emails